# How to check in PyMongo is connection is still alive?

Tags: python, pymongo

How to check in PyMongo is connection is still alive ? Is there any elegant way to do this or just to try one simple query and parser results ?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is an elegant way. Pymongo has the [AutoReconnect](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.1.1/api/pymongo/errors.html#pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect) exception which will be thrown if a previously established connection has been lost. You are supposed to catch this exception and retry the operation which will cause the connection to be reestablished.

A relatively painless way to handle AutoReconnects I've found is to isolate DB operations in separate methods and wrapping them with a decorator similar to this:

```
from pymongo.errors import AutoReconnect

def autoreconnect_retry(fn, retries=3):
    def db_op_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        tries = 0

        while tries < retries:
            try:
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)

            except AutoReconnect:
                tries += 1

        raise Exception("No luck even after %d retries" % retries)

    return db_op_wrapper
```

The usage:

```
@autoreconnect_retry
def insert_foo_record(foo):
    # Perform db operation
    pass

@autoreconnect_retry(20)
def get_foo_record(id):
    # Perform db operation
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

In pymongo2.2 connection url has option of adding additional parameters:

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db>?options
```

one of supported options is connectTimeoutMS ie

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db>?connectTimeoutMS=300
```

in order to extend connection timeout to 300ms

greater versions of pymongo has similar variation of same option

Answer (score 0):

With the solution given you will have errors like *'NoneType' object is not callable*, or *autoreconnect_retry() takes at least 1 argument (1 given)*. Here you have tested and running code to decorate all the methods that performs pymongo operations, based on kristaps answer:

```
from pymongo.errors import AutoReconnect

def autoreconnect_retry(retries=3):
"""
Decorator for connection retrial in mongoDB
"""
def autoreconnect_retry_decorator(fn):
    def db_op_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        tries = 0

        while tries < retries:
            try:
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)

            except AutoReconnect:
                tries += 1

        raise Exception("No luck even after %d retries" % retries)

    return db_op_wrapper
return autoreconnect_retry_decorator
```

Then you can decorate methods with arguments as mentioned:

```
@autoreconnect_retry
def some_pymongo_operation():
    pass

@autoreconnect_retry(20)
def some_pymongo_operation():
    pass
```

Comment: You could have just returned db_op_wrapper and it would have worked. No need to add another decorator on top of another. You have lots of indention errors also.

Comment: @rick112358 if you want to pass in the decorator parameter for the number of retries you need a second wrapper. If you don't want this configuration yes you can skip the outer decorator. Stackoverflow code samples are not expected to work as is nor being compiled dude, it's just code guidelines. Working on production for years with this strategy, no problems, that said on Mongodb 2.6 branch

Comment: I said you can achieve the same without using the second decorator, as shown by kristaps answer. Kristaps' answer is just missing a return statement. Let me tell you what happened, you copy pasted kristaps answer, saw an error message, and while debugging you created this mess without understanding what the actual problem is.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the problem @SouvikMaji , updated the answer